# Javascript onload event not firing inside object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get my head around why this doesn't work and wondered if someone could help me out. Basically I need multiple instances of this object with different images and I need each object to store the image height/width for its associated image for further operations, however the onload event never fires?

Sorry guys to be clear heres the complete code, if you see the TestTheVar function imgW is never set to anything.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  (function() {

  var myTest = new TestObj();
  mytest.TestTheVar();
  })();

function TestObj() {
  this.img = new Image();

  this.img.onload = function(){
    this.imgW = this.img.width;
    this.imgH = this.img.height;
  };

  this.img.src = "reel_normal.PNG";
  this.TestTheVar = function() {
    alert(this.imgW);
  }

}
</script>
```

Comment: How are you testing if the onload event fires?

Comment: Further down the object theres a function that uses imgW it never gets set

Comment: I have similar code working. I used addEventListener but I don't think it makes a difference. Please use console output to double check.

Comment: Note `this` inside the `load` event listener is the image, not your `TestObj` instance. So if you later want to use `imgW`, it must be `this.img.imgW`.

Comment: Your event fires, it just is reading/setting the wrong variable.  P.S. *Please* have your JavaScript console open at *all times* when developing/debugging, you'd probably have seen an error in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here

1) scope

2) timing

Scope, as mentioned in other answers refers to the fact that `this` inside the onload function is the `Image` object and not your TestObj so you would need to do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function() {

    var myTest = new TestObj();
    mytest.TestTheVar();
})();

function TestObj() {
  var self = this;
  this.img = new Image();

  this.img.onload = function(){
    self.imgW = this.width;
    self.imgH = this.height;
  };

  this.img.src = "reel_normal.PNG";

  this.TestTheVar = function() {
    alert(this.imgW);
  }

}
</script>
```

Timing refers to the fact that you cannot assume the image has finished loading by the time you are trying to access height and width. This is what callbacks are good for:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  (function() {

      var myTest = new TestObj(function() {
          myTest.TestTheVar();
      });

  })();

function TestObj(cb) {
  cb = cb || function() {};
  var self = this;
  this.img = new Image();

  this.img.onload = function(){
    self.imgW = this.width;
    self.imgH = this.height;
    cb();
  };

  this.img.src = "reel_normal.PNG";

  this.TestTheVar = function() {
    alert(this.imgW);
  }

}
</script>
```

Comment: You can actually do `this.width` instead of `self.img.width` inside the `onload` function :-)

Comment: I also fixed your second example, you left it as `this.img.width` ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot that's really cleared things up from me, this is my first shot at javascript and the scoping is giving me a bit of a brain ache,  that works perfectly!

Comment: actually theres a problem here, in the callback function myTest is undefined

Comment: actually no its not, its the netbeans debugging ignore me, again thanks a lot!

Comment: Well in my example I had a type where I called the variable `mytest` instead of `myTest` (uppercase T) which could have caused that problem. I have updated the code

Comment: Nah caught that one, was some oddity with netbeans/chrome/debugger - all works great now!

Answer (score 1):

[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is a keyword that belongs to each function.

In the `load` event listener it will be the image, not your `TestObj` instance.

Therefore, you can

- Use `this.img.imgW` to get it:

  ```
  function TestObj() {
    var that = this;
    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.onload = function(){
      this.imgW = this.width;
      this.imgH = this.height;
      that.testTheVar();
    };
    this.img.src = "reel_normal.PNG";
    this.testTheVar = function() {
      alert(this.img.imgW);
    };
  }
  ```
- Store it in your `TestObj` instance:

  ```
  function TestObj() {
    var that = this;
    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.onload = function(){
      that.imgW = this.width;
      that.imgH = this.height;
      that.testTheVar();
    };
    this.img.src = "reel_normal.PNG";
    this.testTheVar = function() {
      alert(this.imgW);
    };
  }
  ```
- Customize `this` inside the event handler to be your `TestObj` instance:

  ```
  function TestObj() {
    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.onload = (function(){
      this.imgW = this.img.width;
      this.imgH = this.img.height;
      this.testTheVar();
    }).bind(this);
    this.img.src = "reel_normal.PNG";
    this.testTheVar = function() {
      alert(this.imgW);
    };
  }
  ```

Comment: Close, but `this.img` won't work inside the `onload` function.